# Regex exact match for non alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search for exact match on non alphanumeric strings e.g. `##` using a regular expression in JavaScript

The match should be for whole 'word' only e.g. `asdf ## adsf` or `##` but not `a##sdf` or `####`

I've tried `^##$`, `\b##\b`, `\w##\w` and have searched for an answer but I'm stumped

Comment: Looks like you want `\B##\B`, please add a couple of test cases.

Comment: That would also match `####`

Comment: So, should they be surrounded with whitespace or be at the start/end of string? `(?<!\S)##(?!\S)`. Or, if you mean there should be no other `#` chars on both ends, use `(?<!#)##(?!#)`

Comment: Ok, try `(?<![#\w])##(?![\w#])`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cqGuoV/2).

Comment: If you explain what you are doing, I could add a workaround for older ECMAScript implementations. These solutions are task-dependent, i.e. they depend on whether you remove, replace with another string, extract or split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need custom word  boundaries, that include both `\w` and `#` patterns.

Use

```
(?<![#\w])##(?![\w#])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cqGuoV/2)

**Details**

- `(?<![#\w])` - (negative lookbehind) no `#` and word char allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `##` -  a `##` char sequence
- `(?![\w#])` - (negative lookahead) no `#` and word char allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Beware that javascript does not support look behind in Firefox (only Chrome, Opera, Edge).

Comment: @PoulBak There are a ton of lookarounds then for that. It only depends on what OP needs in the end, extract or replace. If OP clarifies that, I can add those workarounds. Note that now a lot of browsers and JS environments already support lookbehinds.

Comment: My comment was meant as a comment to OP - I know you can find workarounds :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get the match of the specified "##" alphanumeric word you can choose **regex** package with **findall()** function, which results all founded occurences in a list. You can use the '\' **metacharacter** to find the "##" sequence in the sentence you are serching for. Below I have provided a sample code.

> Code

```
import re 

text = "This ## sentence contains two ##"

result = re.findall("\##", text)
result_count = len(result)

print("Resulted Search: ",result)
print("Result Count: ",result_count)
```

> Output:

```
Resulted Search:  ['##', '##']
Result Count:  2
```

If you are looking for the match like "##" followed by a whitespace you can choose the expression "##\s"
i.e.

```
re.findall("\##\s", text)
```

If you are looking for the match like "##" followed by a whitespace or the match can be even occur at end of the string then you can choose the expression "##\s|##$"
i.e.

```
re.findall("\##\s|\##$", text)
```

or

```
re.findall("\##\s, text+" )
```